# polarization formula for homogeneous polynomials

Tags: polynomials

given a homogeneous polynomial p of dgree n on $R^d$, there is a unique symmetric n-linear functional $B$ on $(R^d)^n$ such that $p(x)=B(x,..,x)$. The question is: Can we get $B$ by means of a polarization formula as in the case $n=2$ for quadratic forms ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that $R$ are the reals.  In any case, you need to be able
to divide by $n!$.

Given that, the answer is **yes**.  I can't locate a reference, but here's
the formula for $n=3$, say:
$$ 6 B(x,y,z) = p(x+y+z) - p(x+y) - p(y+z) - p(z+x) + p(x) + p(y) +
p(z)
$$
which should give you a hint as to the general case.

*Edit by Denis Serre*. This suggests the general formula
$$n!B(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_I(-1)^{n-|I|}p(x_I),\qquad x_I:=\sum_{i\in I}x_i.$$

*Further edit by JMF*.  The formula is proved in this preprint by Erik G.F. Thomas [*A polarization identity for multilinear maps*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.53.3481)

Comment: @Denis: Indeed!