# Reference request: classical polarization argument

Tags: reference-request, qa.quantum-algebra

I am reading the article [ENVELOPING ALGEBRAS OF PRELIE ALGEBRAS,
SOLOMON IDEMPOTENTS AND THE MAGNUS FORMULA](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2159) of Frédéric Chapoton and Frédéric Patras. Many definitions and results used  in this article I do not know yet. In particular, I do not understand what means **classical polarization argument** in the following sentence on page 5:

" [...] Moreover, by the classical polarization argument, setting $a:=l_1+ \cdots l_n$ we get that $l_1\ldots l_n$ " is the $l_1, \ldots, l_n$-multilinear component of $\frac{a^n}{n!};$ [...] "

In which, $L$ is a pre-Lie algebra, $l_1, \ldots, l_n \in L$ and $l_1 \cdots l_n \in S(L)$, the symmetric algebra of $L$.

Can anyone suggest a reference that talk about this "polarization argument"?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98714/generalization-of-the-polarisation-formula-for-symmetric-bilinear-forms-to-symme