# Are the following identities well known?

Tags: polynomials, multilinear-algebra

$$
x \cdot y = \frac{1}{2 \cdot 2 !} \left( (x + y)^2 - (x - y)^2 \right)
$$
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x \cdot y \cdot z &=& \frac{1}{2^2 \cdot 3 !} ((x + y + z)^3 - (x + y - z)^3 \nonumber \\
&-& (x - y + z)^3 + (x - y - z)^3 ), 
\end{eqnarray}
$$
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x \cdot y \cdot z \cdot w &=& \frac{1}{2^3 \cdot 4 !} ( (x + y + z + w)^4 \nonumber \\
&-& (x + y + z - w)^4 - (x + y - z + w)^4 \nonumber \\
&+& (x + y - z - w)^4 - (x - y + z + w)^4 \nonumber \\
&+& (x - y + z - w)^4 + (x - y - z + w)^4 \nonumber \\
&-& (x - y - z - w)^4 ). 
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The identity that rewrites a product of $n$ variables $( n \ge 2$, $n \in \boldsymbol{\mathbb{Z}_+})$ as additions of $n$ th power functions is as given below:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
& &x_0 \cdots x_1 \cdot x_{n-1} = \frac{1}{2^{n - 1} \cdot n !} \cdot \sum_{j = 0}^{2^{ n - 1} -1} ( - 1 )^{\sum_{m = 1}^{n - 1} \sigma_m(j)} \times ( x_0 + (-1)^{\sigma_1(j)} x_1 + \cdots + (- 1)^{\sigma_{n - 1}(j)} x_{n - 1})^n, \\
& &\sigma_m(j) = r(\left\lfloor \frac{j}{2^{m - 1}}\right\rfloor, 2), m (\ge 1), j (\ge 0) \in \mathbb{Z}_+, \; \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor = \max \{ n \in \mathbb{Z}_+ ; n \le x, x \in \mathbb{R} \}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where $r(\alpha, \beta)$,  $\alpha, \beta (\ge 1) \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ means the remainder of the division of $\alpha$ by $\beta$ such that $r(\alpha, \beta)$ $=$ $\alpha - \beta \left\lfloor \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right\rfloor$

Comment: Why do you need to recode the subsets of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\right\}$ as numbers in $\left\{0,1,\ldots,2^{n-1}-1\right\}$ ?

Comment: I intend to constructively make an one sided approximation method of a continuous function of many variables by using the general type identity above. Therefore, I summarized the general type identity above as a constructive form. I need to use $\{0,1,...,2^{n-1}\}$ type.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Although not the exactly the same due to $2^{n-1}$ instead of $2^n$ terms, the OP's formula seems to be essentially the well-known *polarization* formula for homogeneous polynomials, which is stated as following:

> Any polynomial $f$, homogeneous of degree $n$ can be written as $f(x)=H(x,\ldots,x)$ for a specific multilinear form $H$. One has the following [*polarization formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_of_an_algebraic_form) for $H$ (see also [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61884/polarization-formula-for-homogeneous-polynomials)):
>   \begin{equation*}
>  H(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \frac{1}{2^n n!}\sum_{s \in \{\pm 1\}^n}s_1\ldots s_n f\Bigl(\sum\nolimits_{j=1}^n s_jx_j\Bigr)
> \end{equation*}

In your case, $f=x^n$, so $H(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = x_1\cdots x_n$ (please note off by 1 indexing).

Comment: The OP's formula is obtained upon division by $2$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: thanks! I think I got confused due to the extra $\lfloor . \rfloor$ notation in the OP, and did not feel like verifying :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. I found these identies from n = 2 until n= 6, 22 years ago. Then 3 years ago, I summarized the general type identity above,  by using a remainder form. I also proved that  general type identity above, by using a recurrence formula. Now I understood that the  general type identity above, is a special form of polarization formula in the case of $f =x^n$, and H(x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1})$.

Comment: @HideakiOkazaki You are welcome! Very interesting to note that you discovered some of these 22 years ago. I don't know though how old these polarization identities actually are....

Comment: @Suvrit. Plz, have you a reference for the OP's formula. Thanks.

Comment: @mostafa You can see this polarization identity for instance in http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504397.pdf --- it is mentioned in other places too; I don't know the "oldest / canonical" citation for this though; maybe Alexandrov...